# Simple example for c# aspx threading

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm searching for days a very simple example of using `threads` for aspx sites with c#. Found some for vb.net but can't get them work with c#.

I need a `thread` or `backgroundworker` for my aspx site with queries a database and do some calculation with the responded values. It takes very long and I want to update my site while calculating to inform the user.

I tried it with an `ajax update panel` but get a timeout error (think the calculation takes too long). Also tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wkays279.aspx but get an error that asynch threading not allowed.

So has someone a link or a simple example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this link from the official asp.net website, it has code samples as well: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

For a higher-level view: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx

It's not background worker but the new async/await task-based asynchrony.

Here's a sample of synchronous versus asynchronous methods, from the first article

Synchronous example:

```
public List<Gizmo> GetGizmos()
{
    var uri = Util.getServiceUri("Gizmos");
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Gizmo>>(
            webClient.DownloadString(uri)
        );
    }
}
```

Versus async:

```
public async Task<List<Gizmo>> GetGizmosAsync()
{
    var uri = Util.getServiceUri("Gizmos");
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Gizmo>>());
    }
}
```

In the example these methods are contained in the GizmoService class, which is your "back end" C#. You can call these methods from your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Gizmos()
{
    ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Synchronous";
    var gizmoService = new GizmoService();
    return View("Gizmos", gizmoService.GetGizmos());
}
public async Task<ActionResult> GizmosAsync()
{
    ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Asynchronous";
    var gizmoService = new GizmoService();
    return View("Gizmos", await gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Thread classes directly you could use the PageAsyncTask class. The following page also includes an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx